# Проблема с импортом react gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Доброе время суток проблема с импоротом react ошибки покзывает на первый импорт все установил через npm

```
let React = require('react');
let ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: так не делается вы что смотрите уроки react 15 что ли?

Comment: Документация это

Comment: Как тогда делается ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
```